# How to redirect urls starting with numbers

Tags: .htaccess

What will be a 301 redirect rule using htaccess to redirect urls similar to

domain.com/community/783-anystring-string/profile

to

domain.com/community/

or

any url matching this type of format

domain.com/community/123-anystring-string/...

to

domain.com/community/

Basically I want to redirect any urls domain.com/community/(starting with numbers)-string...

to domain.com/community/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `mod_rewrite`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^community/[0-9]* /community [R=301,L]
```

I think. That may not work, I can't test it right now :/

Comment: Thanks....but that is not working.

Firefox says - Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: I changed the rule to

RewriteRule ^community/[0-9]-* /community [R=301,L]

because the url starts with number and hyphen..now it is working. Thanks for pointing in the right direction :)